# Monero sent to own wallet by accident but it doesn't show up?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

Instead of sending it to the correct address, I've send it to my own wallet's receiving address. The wallet has been synced and I even changed the blockheight info .

Comment: It has over 263 confirmations too.

Comment: You could try a `show_transfers out` to see if your transaction did take place.

Comment: You can check your transaction at ex. https://www.exploremonero.com/ or one of the other blockchain explorers.

Comment: The transfer did take place. It has confirmations.

Comment: Did you do the `show_transfers out` and check in a blockchain explorer ?

Comment: I'm using the Gui. And I checked the blockchain explorer.

Comment: I also checked payment proof and it appears I've send it to not my own address but the correct address of xmr.to so they're having a bug and I hope they can resolve it soon.

Comment: You should be all good then. Those guys know what they are doing.

Comment: @zenchi8 reading this comment thread it appears the question is invalid. You sent to xmr.to not "sent to own wallet"?? If you still have an issue can you either rephrase your question or close it please.

Comment: @jtgrassie - I marked this as duplicate of the more generic missing Q&A.